# chrome:headless mode the side bar not visible

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Sidebar element is not visble in headless mode.

My test running fine but when I used chrome:headless mode then the test always fails. Even I use wait option to wait for element but always fails.

I used  screenshot option and I found that the whole left side bar is not visible.

I tried with different browser and got same result. This issue is only in browser:headless.

Answer (score 1):

try using [maximizewindow](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/testcontroller/maximizewindow.html) before running your tests. If the problem still persists, please send us an example project.

Comment: Where can I send the example in private because I am not allwed to post publically.

The issue I found is that in headless mode, all the tests run in tablet mode(after analyzing  screen shots). I already try with maximizewind and even change the width of the page. The page is always in tablet mode.

Comment: You can send it at support@devexpress.com. Please note that our policy prevents us from accessing internal resources without prior written approval from a site owner. If you want us to research the problem directly on your side, please ask the website owner to send us written confirmation at support@devexpress.com. It must permit DevExpress personnel to remotely access the website and its internal resources for research/testing/and debugging purposes.